# Pulling code from Bitbucket onto a AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitbucket

After using RDP to access my EC2 I'm trying to use Git to pull my code from Bitbucket onto the instance so I can access it there.

Currently I'm getting the error

```
ssh: connect to host *******: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository
```

Is there some changes I need to make to the security groups to be able to access bitbucket?

I've attempted to:

- Use ssh config setting but it doesn't make a difference
- Change some security group settings but I don't really know what I'm doing so I might be changing the wrong thing

Comment: Did you try to resolve the domain name? First, check that.

Comment: You can try once with https clone using git clone https://USER@bitbucket.org/REPO.git

Answer (score 0):

The "timed out" error suggests that something is preventing your EC2 instance's attempts to connect to the remote host. (The message would be "connection refused" if the receiving end were rejecting the connection.) Port 22 (the default SSH port) is very often restricted in both directions, so I'd make sure that the security group permits *outbound* connections to that port.

If you're using Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.org) then you could also try the `altssh.bitbucket.org` hostname - that specific hostname uses (the non-standard) port 443 for SSH access, since 443 is rarely firewalled on outbound connections. (GitHub and GitLab have similar trickery going with their own specific hostnames `ssh.github.com` and `ssh.gitlab.com`, for the same reason.) You'd need to clone with `git clone ssh://git@altssh.bitbucket.org:443/OWNER/REPO`, or update an existing clone with `git remote set-url origin ssh://git@altssh.bitbucket.org:443/OWNER/REPO` (assuming that `origin` is what you call the remote), but once that's done you won't have to do anything different to connect.